# Magento2 integration with alertifyjs

Tags: magento2, alertifyjs

Can anybody let me know, is it possible to integrate alertifyjs in magento2

Please find the below link:

http://alertifyjs.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to create requirejs dependency which will represent alertifyjs + add css files to head.  Maybe you will need to wrap alertifyjs javascript code with "define" requirejs block but im not sure.